# Performance issues when merging two dataframe columns into one on millions rows with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am trying to merge two address columns into one and separate the resulting string with '--'. The dataset has 10 million rows and 33 columns - but the number of rows grows for a million or so a month. This line in Pandas/Python is very slow. Any ideas of how can I make it faster and scalable for future use?

```
df['address'] = df[['address1', 'address2']].apply(lambda x: '--'.join(x.dropna().astype(str).values), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

With my solution, you have to parse your column with string type:

First:

```
df[["address1", "address2"]] = df[["address1", "address2"]].dropna().astype(str)
```

Then define concatenation fonction to concatenate two strings

```
def concat_string(a, b):
    return a + '--' +  b
```

Finally I advise you to work with pandas series, it will be improve your operations.

Here I apply [combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine.html) (from pandas series) with in param the function define above concat_string. concat_string takes in param element from df['address1'] and combine them with df['address2'].

Combine vectorize the operation, it "replaces" traditional loop.

```
df['address'] = df['address1'].combine(df['address2'], concat_string)
```

Benchmark:

```
df.shape => (10000, 2)

%time df['address'] = df[['address1', 'address2']].apply(lambda x: '--'.join(x.dropna().astype(str).values), axis=1)
CPU times: user 4.6 s, sys: 18.8 ms, total: 4.62 s
Wall time: 4.64 s

%time df['address_Test'] = df['address1'].combine(df['address2'], concat_string)
CPU times: user 302 ms, sys: 27.6 ms, total: 329 ms
Wall time: 321 ms
```

Comment: Thank you @Jean s. I can't comment on your answer but you are not calling concat_string method with any parameters here: df['address_Test'] = df['address1'].combine(df['address2'], concat_string) I guess I will still need to loop there, to call it with params which will affect performance?